# Solidity upgradeable linked Libraries

Tags: solidity, libraries

What would be the best way to deploy upgradeable libraries?
If I am not mistaken, when deploying a contract that uses linked libraries, the contract's bytecode contains the libraries addresses, which means that by default, the libraries can not be updated, we would need to redeploy the contract.
I was wondering if there is some kind of library proxy pattern that could help with that...

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is sth you meant:
https://docs.openzeppelin.com/upgrades-plugins/1.x/proxies

But if you want a contract to use functions from a library/or another contract then you could consider a proxy or linking this library in your contract with making it possible to change the linked address for example:
(note you should only allow the owner to change these addresses)

```
contract InteractWithLibraries{
address s_linkedLibraryAddress;

function linkLibrary(address _libraryAddress) public {
require(_libraryAddress != address(0), "invalid address");
  s_linkedLibraryAddress = _libraryAddress
}

function doSthWithLibrary() public view{
 //add require for address != 0
 libraryImpl localUsedLibrary = libraryImpl(s_linkedLibraryAddress);
 localUsedLibrary.doSth();
}

}

abstract contract libraryImpl {
//here are the functions you want access from your contract
function doSth() public view;
}
```

by calling your "linkLibrary" with the address of your updated library you can now use your new library.
Clearly the functions itself can not be changed only the logic or calls at your new library can.

I hope this helped